# The TextBackend supports only expressions over a 1D range: Implicit plotting in Sympy

Tags: python, plot, expression, sympy

On doing the following,

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
p1 = plot_implicit((Eq(x**2 + y**2, 5)))
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    p1 = plot_implicit((Eq(x**2 + y**2, 5)))
  File "/home/tinkidinki/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot_implicit.py", line 377, in plot_implicit
    p.show()
  File "/home/tinkidinki/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 187, in show
    self._backend.show()
  File "/home/tinkidinki/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 1101, in show
    'The TextBackend supports only expressions over a 1D range')
ValueError: The TextBackend supports only expressions over a 1D range
```

It doesn't seem to get affected by making it a one-variable expression. How do you plot implicitly in Sympy?

Answer (score 15):

If you install matplotlib it will use that for plotting instead of TextBackend. I ran `pip install matplotlib` and when I tried your expression/command it worked.